# No Clang component for MSVC found

Tags: python, c++, anaconda, clang, nuitka

I'm using anaconda Nuitka packages to obfuscate my python script PASS.py
I've done below steps:

1. installed Microsoft visual studio community edition 2022 with python development and Desktop development with C++
2. installed individual components:
   [image]
   [image]
3. I have also installed microsoft_build_tools_2015_update_3_x86_x64 and visual_2015_redistributable_update_3_x86
4. added to path system variable: clang.exe, clang++.exe and clang-cl.exe,
   in my system there are in:

   C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\VC\Tools\Llvm\bin
   C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\VC\Tools\Llvm\x64\bin
   C:\Users\Dalia\anaconda3\pkgs\clang-14.0.6-h44fa016_0\Library\bin\
5. on anaconda prompt, I run below command

   python -m nuitka --clang --follow-imports PASS.py

it shows below message:

```
 Nuitka-Options:INFO: Used command line options: --clang --follow-imports PASS.py
    Nuitka:INFO: Starting Python compilation with Nuitka '0.6.16' on Python '3.9' commercial None.
    Nuitka:INFO: Completed Python level compilation and optimization.
    Nuitka:INFO: Generating source code for C backend compiler.
    Nuitka:INFO: Running data composer tool for optimal constant value handling.
    Nuitka:INFO: Running C level backend compilation via Scons.
    TypeError: not all arguments converted during string formatting:
      File "C:\Users\Dalia\ANACON~1\lib\SITE-P~1\nuitka\build\Backend.scons", line 334:
        addClangClPathFromMSVC(env=env, target_arch=target_arch)
      File "C:\Users\Dalia\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\nuitka\build\SconsUtils.py", line 315:
        scons_details_logger.info("No Clang component for MSVC found." % clang_dir)
```

Comment: [This might be of interest](https://github.com/Nuitka/Nuitka/issues/1778)
also I wouldn't use the anaconda prompt, as it might set it's own variables that may interfere with what you are doing. That being said... the easiest thing you can do is figure out if anaconda prompt can at least find `clang-cl`, because if not, then that might be your actual issue.

Comment: no such option `clang-cl`, either `clang` or `cl`

Comment: I'm not a clang expert, but I believe that MSVC invokes `clang-cl`. So you are most-likely missing the path for clang-cl within anaconda. Or atleast the `C:\Users\Dalia\ANACON~1\lib\SITE-P~1\nuitka\build\Backend.scons` doesn't register it. This is most likely the source of all your issues. Ideally you want to invoke that command from a normal console/shell.

Comment: I've installed Nuitka package through anaconda, can't use normal console to run nuitka command, I've to use anaconda prompt

Comment: Based on what the author of the nuitka package provided in his tutorial, having a "special" setup is what leads to problems. Even his issues have to have these questions answered (If you've checked the issue under the link and read through the discussion you would know that). I'm here just providing you with ideas on how to fix this yourself. That's all I can do and trying to set it up as his tutorial suggests is probably the only fool proof way on how to get it working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution:
just write cmd without "--clang"

```
python -m nuitka --follow-imports PASS.py
```